# how to make a gadget for facebook which will share any iframe in users wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to make a gadget for Facebook which has the ability to share an HTML iframe on a user's wall? I mean if a Facebook user clicks on the `[Share]` button then it will share an iframe on their wall.

Comment: This isn't possible, for a multitude of security reasons.

Answer (score 5):

This is **not** possible,

You should at least check Facebook's documentation regarding the [available communication channels](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#channels) for applications

You might have seen people sharing videos... but this does not mean you can actually add HTML tags to embed your own external content.

Comment: I'm out of votes today, otherwise I would have voted for this answer - it's well written and spot on.

Comment: @awoodland Happy to vote on your behalf. This is a well-written answer with a good reference.